# Forward Outlook calendar in email using Outlook for Mac 2015 (15.17)

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar

I would like to forward my Outlook calendar events to my Google Calendar account. Is this possible in Outlook for Mac 2015?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013 you can select the calender view, click on e-mail calendar, select the options you want and it will create a .ics file and html view in a new email. The ics should be possible to import to your google calendar.